# Encrypting Decrypting sessions

Tags: php, session, encryption

I have this code which stores sessions inside the database.

```
public function read($id)  
{
   // $id=rtrim(@mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, 'qwerty', base64_decode($id), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,  md5(md5('protect me')) ),'\0');

    $result = mysqli_query($this->link,"SELECT Session_Data FROM Session WHERE Session_Id = '".$id."' AND Session_Expires > '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'");
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        return $row['Session_Data'];
    }else{
        return "";
    }
}


public function write($id, $data)
{
    //$id=@base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, 'qwerty', $id, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5('protect me'))));
    $DateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $NewDateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($DateTime.' + 1 hour'));
    $result = mysqli_query($this->link,"REPLACE INTO Session SET Session_Id = '".$id."', Session_Expires = '".$NewDateTime."', Session_Data = '".$data."'");
    if($result){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

In the above code i have commented out the encrypting and decrypting lines which actually encrypts and decrypts the **$id** before storing inside the database or reading from the database.

What exactly happens is that when i don't do this encryption and decryption process.The sessions works exactly as they should but if i were to do this process the session data that are getting stored inside gets replaced with the current session.

To make my question more clear

I have two php files

*1)* test1.php

```
<?php

require_once('inc.session.php');

session_start();

   $_SESSION['var1'] = "My Portuguese text: SOU Gaucho!";
?>
```

*2)* test2.php

```
<?php
//page 2
require_once('inc.session.php');

 session_start();
$_SESSION['wef']="abbaba";

if(isset($_SESSION['var1'])){
echo $_SESSION['var1'];
  }
 ?>
```

**Database**:

[image]

Above one is without the encryption process while the latter one is with the encryption process.As it can be clear from the pic that the session data is not exactly the same as before.Why is this happening ?

Comment: You may registering `var1` before decrypting session_id, and when you load session_id as current session, var1 is just removing because it is not the same session. But I'm just predicting. Could you please share your full code base related this process. It is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Before you even delve into writing cryptography (i.e. encryption) code, you should try to [learn about application security](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/gentle-introduction-application-security):

- [Preventing SQL Injection](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/preventing-sql-injection-in-php-applications-easy-and-definitive-guide) is best done by using **prepared statements**.
- You're using [*unauthenticated encryption*](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong).
- Your code does something very similar to [this Crypto Fails article](http://www.cryptofails.com/post/70059605630/php-encrypt-decrypt-binary-vs-hex)
- [Don't use mcrypt](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong).

Why are you even encrypting your session ID in the database to begin with? Who are you hiding it from? Just store it wholesale.

Comment: I was encrypting the session id as i thought it might prevent session hijacking

Comment: i tried prepared statement on my php code but it gives me the following error.Would you mind giving it a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35263758/prepare-not-defined

Comment: what to do now ?how do i prevent myself from sql injection?

Comment: "I was encrypting the session id as i thought it might prevent session hijacking "

No. [Just use TLS](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/fast-track-safe-and-secure-php-sessions).