# Prepare not defined

Tags: php, session, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have tried setting sessions which are stored in database.I have achieved this through implementing *SessionHandlerInterface* class.However i havenot used prepared statements before but now i  want to implement prepared statements in order to make it sql injection proof.However , when i try the prepare method it shows me an error

> Method Prepare not defined in Class

i even tried extending *mysqli_stmt* class which contains the methods for prepared statements.

> This is the full code of session class that stores sessions inside the database.

http://codepad.org/KmLtO9ym

> Part of the code to make the question much more clear

```
class SysSession implements SessionHandlerInterface
{
   private $link;

public function open($savePath, $sessionName)
{
    $link = new mysqli("localhost","root","","cakenbake");
    if($link){
        $this->link = $link;
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
public function close()
{
    mysqli_close($this->link);
    return true;
}
public function read($id)
{


    $result = mysqli_query($this->link,"SELECT Session_Data FROM Session WHERE Session_Id = '".$id."' AND Session_Expires > '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'");

    /*$result=$this->link->prepare("Some query inside")
     * This shows up an error stating prepare method not found
     *
     */

    if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        return $row['Session_Data'];
    }else{
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked $this->link has connection object??

Comment: connection object as in? i have declared $link as the connection object at the starting and the using '$this->link' i can access it, i guess.

Comment: Yes. But check your credentials twice. Also make sure that your "open" method called first. After calling that method you can call "read" method.

Comment: First of all why do you use object oriented style with Procedural style - stick to one - `mysqli_query` should be in your case `$this->link->query`. second please write the exact error message you are getting

Comment: updated my post as well as this is not working as welll..i dont know why

Comment: The problem is only in your IDE? Or does *PHP* actually give you any issues when you run the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my IDE.It was the one who was showing errors.Restarted my IDE and it worked fine.